# cvSetErrMode not working

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to use Parent mode in OpenCV. It seems that OpenCV is ignoring the cvSetErrMode() call.

```
fprintf(stderr, "cvSetErrMode(%d) returned %d\n", 
    CV_ErrModeParent, cvSetErrMode(CV_ErrModeParent));
fprintf(stderr, "cvGetErrMode() returned %d\n", cvGetErrMode());
```

This returns:

```
cvSetErrMode(1) returned 0
cvGetErrMode() returned 0
```

It seems to me that cvGetErrMode() should return 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions are deprecated in OpenCV 2.x OpenCV still provides stub implementation for backward compatibility.

Comment: Sure enough....  `brew info opencv
opencv 2.2
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/
Depends on: cmake, pkg-config, libtiff, jasper, tbb
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.2 (123 files, 39M)`